# TOC for High Level Design Document,.NET

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I'm looking out for a template for a high level design document. What should be covered in there. Something like a TOC which I can expand upon. Any help would be highly appreciated !!! Basically we are building an ASP .NET, WCF, nHibernate+Castle windsor based web application.

A real world document serving the above need with your project specifics removed would be an awesome starter !!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice set of templates here:

http://smartbear.com/community/resources/templates/

I imagine the *Functional Specification* and *Detail Design* templates will be the ones of most interest to you.

Comment: Thanks .. this does help and I guess I need to add/omit sections to tailor for my project !